# Javascript print all the status at a time using request node module

Tags: javascript, promise, request-promise

I'm new to javascript and promises, I had a requirement where I need to get the `http` status of my URL's(i have 10 URL's) all at a time (Not sequentialy).
So I wrote below code.

```
var request = require('request');

var fun = function(i) {
  request('http://myapp' + i + '.com', function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response && response.statusCode, i);
  });
};

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  fun(i);
}
```

but I'm getting
status1 then status2 then status3 and so on..... my requirement is to print all the status at one time.

then tried below code

```
var request = require('request');

var fun = function(myapp) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('http://' + myapp + '.com', function(error, response, body) {
      resolve(response && response.statusCode);
    });
  });
};

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  fun('myapp' + i).then(function(val1) {
    console.log(val1);
  });
}
```

but still, I'm getting status1 then status2 then status3 and so on.....
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could collect all the promises in an array, then use Promise.all on that to get an array of results:

```
  const promises = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push( fun('myapp' + i));


  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried your solution but getting undefined values. const promises = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises.push(fun());
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(val){
       console.log(val);
    });


}


function fun(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request('https://google.co.uk', function (error, response, body) {
            resolve(response && response.statusCode);
        });
    });
};

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. It executes asynchronously in parallel.

However you are confused into seeing output be printed in sequence (or what looks like sequence) but this is normal, no matter if parallel or synhronous, output (as it is coded will be printed one after the other, maybe not in same order).

if you want to output all at once when finished, do sth like the following:

```
var request = require('request');
var finished = new Array(10);
var numFinished = 0;

var fun = function(i) {
  request('http://myapp' + i + '.com', function(error, response, body) {
    finished[i] = response && response.statusCode ? response.statusCode : 'No response';
    numFinished++;
  });
};

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  fun(i);
}

var timer = setTinterval(function(){
   if ( 10 <= numFinished )
   {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log(finished.join(',')); // print all at once
   }
}, 500);
```

Or if you use promises you can do:

```
var request = require('request');

var fun = function(myapp) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request('http://' + myapp + '.com', function(error, response, body) {
       resolve(response && response.statusCode ? response.statusCode : 'No response');
    });
  });
};

var promises = new Array(10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises[i] = fun('myapp' + i);

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
   console.log(results.join(',')); // print all at once
});
```

Comment: Urgh. No need for polling if you have promises.

Comment: sure I did not use promises only callbacks (based on 1st version). Let me update with promises

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried your solution but getting ,,,,,,,,, as out put.              
        var fun = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request('https://google.co.uk', function(error, response, body) {
            resolve(response && response.statusCode);
        });
    });
};

var promises = new Array(10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    promises[i] = fun();

    Promise.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        console.log(results.join(',')); // print all at once
    });
}

Comment: @Sid, that means that response was null or undefined for all requests. Updated my answer to better illustrate the case